# How to compile CUDA code that uses std::chrono and date?

Tags: c++, datetime, c++14, c++-chrono

The NVCC compiler refuses to compile the code below (using `.cu` extension), as it does not handle Howard Hinnant's date library well. NVCC is calling GCC 6.4.0. The C++ compiler itself has no problem at all with this simple example. How can I solve this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "date.h"

int main()
{
    const auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    const auto daypoint = date::floor<date::days>(time);
    const auto ymd = date::year_month_day{daypoint};

    std::cout << ymd.year() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
../include/date.h:162:27: error: ‘const intmax_t std::__ratio_multiply<std::ratio<24l>, std::ratio<3600l> >::__gcd1’ is private within this context
 using days = std::chrono::duration
                           ^~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                            
/nfs/admin/hpc/sw/RedHatEnterpriseServer7/GCCcore/6.4.0/include/c++/6.4.0/ratio:289:32: note: declared private here
       static const intmax_t __gcd1 =
                                ^~~~~
```

Comment: The latest release of the library (v3.0.0) should compile successfully with NVCC https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/pull/510

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I can recommend is to send a bug report to Nvidia.  Here is a reduced test case:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ratio>

using days = std::chrono::duration
    <int, std::ratio_multiply<std::ratio<24>, std::chrono::hours::period>>;

int main() {}
```

Comment: Thanks, if it is a bug, then my question doesn't really belong at SO. Sorry for blaming your library!

Comment: Not a problem.  I'm happy to help get to the bottom of this.  Since I don't have access to the NVCC compiler, can you confirm that my reduced test case does not work with the NVCC compiler?

Comment: I confirm that. This does not compile either: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio_multiply it seems that `ratio_multiply` is the source of the error.

Comment: Hi @HowardHinnant, I hit the same issue and was able to work around this by just replacing the instantiations of `std::ratio_multiply` and `std::ratio_divide` with explicit values in the `date/date.h` header file. I'm wondering if you would be interested in merging if I created a PR for this workaround (I completely understand if the answer is no, this is a cuda issue and not a date library problem but it would be nice to have the library work out-of-the-box)?

Comment: Does adding `::type` to the closing angle bracket of `ratio_multiply` work?  `using days = std::chrono::duration
    <int, std::ratio_multiply<std::ratio<24>, std::chrono::hours::period>::type>;`

Comment: No, adding `::type` does not work, I still see the same error message

Comment: Sorry, no.  I could almost stand doing it for `days` and `weeks`, but `months` and `years` would just be too obscure.  It might help if you tell Nvidia that this library is going to be part of the C++20 std::lib and they will have to deal with it then.  So they might as well deal with it now.

Comment: I was planning on adding comments next to the code indicating how that value was computed or I could write a custom ratio_multiply but it’s fine it that is not acceptable. I guess I’ll use a patched fork for now and hope Nvidia fixes their compiler soon. Thanks for pushing for time zones in the c++ standard.